# Using imessage deleting message

Tags: mac, macos, messages

When deleting imessages on my mac, I want to press space bar so that i can quickly click on "delete" however tab doesn't work and I can't seem to focus on the pop up that has two options "cancel" and "delete".  Basically I would like to press tab and then press the space bar to delete the imessage.

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you using? On High Sierra I do not get a prompt asking for confirmation when deleting conversations.

Comment: High sierra 10.13.4

Comment: ah, i see, this only appears if "Save history when conversations are closed" is unticked in Messages Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard
Select the Tab "Shortcuts"

At the bottom there is the option "Full Keyboard Access". Switch that from "Text boxes and lists only" to "All controls".

Then you can use tab + space to select the Delete option in the dialog.

Comment: I followed your advice, but still need to move my cursor to delete to actually delete a message. Pressing return does nothing. Also, pressing command-d does nothing. The only way I've been able to delete a message on my Mac running High Sierra is to click on the x then move from cancel to delete and click on delete. Any other suggestions for High Sierra users?

Answer (score 0):

Just like in Mojave, Catalina also makes it possible to delete the message using CMD + Del and to hold CMD and press D afterwards to dismiss the confirmation dialogue.

Watch it in action here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-MUcKjbhzM